# Load Google Map in iPhone Application

Tags: iphone

How can I load a google Map in my iPhone application?

Here I don't require entire web page, but just the graph part (zoomable).

any sample code link.(if available).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use MapKit framework.
There is no official example code, but if you google it you can easily find 3rd-party tutorials such as [this one](http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2009/04/02/iphone-sdk-30-playing-with-map-kit/).
Here is the link to [official documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/navigation/Frameworks/CocoaTouch/MapKit/)

Also there is open-source mapping framework [Route me](http://code.google.com/p/route-me/) that you can look at

Comment: Google: "download iphone mapkit".  (Note: This broadly generalizable technique turns out to be remarkably useful.  I predict great things from Google, Inc.)

Answer (score 3):

If you are targetting OS 3.0, you can use MapKit for this.